# Problem with your Heroku login. Heroku has deleted my account because I haven't logged in for some time, Is there a way to retrieve my db?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

The app has been running and fed with data from external users but I didn't log in in the dashboard myself.
I missed the last email from heroku that they would delete my app.
Can someone help please.
I have contacted their support but I haven't gotten any response yet.
I was a free user, I didn't have a package, nor was I paying because I had a small app.

I have contacted their support but I haven't gotten any response yet.
Is there a way I can retrieve the postgres db?
They say in the website that they will delete the data based on the new policy starting from November 2022.
this is a very important project.
I'm not sure If I would pay them they would get it back to me.
Did anyone face this before?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.